# Interpret Gcov report for class objects

Tags: c++, class, code-coverage, gcov

I am doing code coverage on the class `cashier` and my teacher gave a very brief teaching on the meaning of the report which i feel is very important for the development of my software engineering skills hence i would need your advice on the intepretation of the following gcov report . I would appreciate any links or articles which would help in my understanding of gcov

Thanks

**Header file**

```
#ifndef CASHIER_H
#define CASHIER_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class cashier 
{
public:

        void setID(string);
    string getID();

    void setPassword(string);
    string getPassword();

    void settries(int);
    int gettries();
        void increase_tries();

private:
    string ID;
    string Password;
    int tries;



};

#endif  /* CASHIER_H */
```

**Implementation file**

```
#include "cashier.h"




void cashier::setID(string value)
{
    this->ID = value;
}

void cashier::setPassword(string value)
{

    this->Password = value;

}

string cashier::getID()
{
    return this->ID;
}

string cashier::getPassword()
{
    return this->Password;
}

void cashier::settries(int value)
{
    this->tries=value;
}
int cashier::gettries()
{
    return this->tries;
}
void cashier::increase_tries()
{
    this->tries = this->tries + 1 ;

}
```

I type the following commands into the command prompt to use gcov on the class

```
gcov -b cashier.gnco
```

I got the following results A

```
File 'cashier.cpp'
Lines executed:100.00% of 18 //what does the 18 mean 
No branches                  //what does no branches mean
Calls executed:100.00% of 4   // what does 4 mean ??
cashier.cpp:creating 'cashier.cpp.gcov'

File '/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h' // Where did this come from ??
Lines executed:0.00% of 2
No branches
Calls executed:0.00% of 1
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:creating 'basic_string.h.gcov
```

I type in the following command

```
gcov -f cashier.gnco
```

I got the following results B

```
Function '_ZN7cashier8settriesEi' // does this refer to the function :settries
Lines executed:100.00% of 3       // my teacher doesnt think so but i feel it refer
                                  //to it , who is correct??

Function '_ZN7cashier8gettriesEv'
Lines executed:100.00% of 2

Function '_ZN7cashier14increase_triesEv'
Lines executed:100.00% of 3

Function '_ZN7cashier11getPasswordEv'
Lines executed:100.00% of 2

Function '_ZN7cashier5getIDEv'
Lines executed:100.00% of 2

Function '_ZNSsaSERKSs'
Lines executed:0.00% of 2

Function '_ZN7cashier11setPasswordESs'
Lines executed:100.00% of 3

Function '_ZN7cashier5setIDESs'
Lines executed:100.00% of 3

File 'cashier.cpp'
Lines executed:100.00% of 18
cashier.cpp:creating 'cashier.cpp.gcov'

File '/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h'
Lines executed:0.00% of 2
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:creating 'basic_string.h.gcov'
```

**My questions for Result A**

1) What does **18** mean and its significance in `Lines executed:100.00% of 18`

2) What does `no branches` mean

3) what does **4** means and its significance in `Calls executed:100.00% of 4`

4) What does the entire paragraph mean

```
 File '/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h'
    Lines executed:0.00% of 2
    No branches
    Calls executed:0.00% of 1
    /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:creating 'basic_string.h.gcov
```

**My questions for Result B**

1) All the functions names etc: **:'_ZN7cashier8settriesEi'** almost matches cashier functions names etc: void settries(int) , I think it refers to the same function but my teacher feels otherwise , who is correct ??

2) What does the 3 mean in `Lines executed:100.00% of 3`for the function :'_ZN7cashier8settriesEi'

Answer (score 3):

Result A:

1. 18 lines of your code was executed after launch program (relate to cashier.cpp).
2. Your code hasn't any conditions.
3. 4 lines was executed from 4 instrumented (relate to cashier.h)
4. Some lines of std::string became part of coverage. You should exclude std::string from coverage report(gcov -e)

Result B:

1. Yes
2. 3 lines was executed from 3 instrumented.

P.S.
 If you interested in gcov you can install lcov - it is gui representation on gcov report.

Comment: The answer to B.1) is that these are mangled, as @Melebius already pointed out. `Computernerds` teacher is correct, unless the mangled names are exactly equal, they don't refer to the same function.

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl so does that mean that mangled function names refer to the functions in cashier.h ??

Comment: I believe they do, yes.

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl what do you mean by instructments ??

Answer (score 2):

The names like `_ZN7cashier8settriesEi` are [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) names and they definitely refer to the functions like `cashier::settries()` in this case.

`Lines executed` is simply the number of lines in the source file which were gone through during the program run. You should look into the detailed results (see [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcov#Example)) to examine which ones are the actual *executable* and *executed* lines.

`No branches` means that there are no points of decision like `if` statements in the code.

`Calls executed` are the calls of functions from that file <strike>to the functions of that file</strike>.

```
void cashier::setID(string value)
{
    this->ID = value; // call to string::operator=()
}

void cashier::setPassword(string value)
{
    this->Password = value; // call to string::operator=()
}

string cashier::getID()
{
    return this->ID; // call to copy-constructor of string
}

string cashier::getPassword()
{
    return this->Password; // call to copy-constructor of string
}
```

These four methods are calling `std::string`’s methods, although it’s not written explicitly. (See my comments to the code above.)
 The other three methods manipulate variables of basic type `int` and this requires no function calls.

Comment: I have 7 functions in cashier.h yet there are only 4 function calls , which four function calls are executed ??

Comment: @Computernerd See update. Sorry for my mistake with `Calls executed`, now it’s corrected and explained.

Comment: Why do the four other methods require no function call ??

Comment: @Computernerd Those four I copied process `std::string` variables while the other three process just `int` variables. `int` is a built-in type and compiler knows how to assign to or copy them. However, `std::string` is a class. The compiler must be told how to do such things using methods like copy-constructor and operator=().